# Is there a GTK 3 API to completely disable themes from affecting your app?

Tags: themes, gtk3

I have a very specific app scenario where I need to prevent any GTK/GNOME (or other) theme from affecting control hints and decoration information. I just spent most of the previous weekend digging through the GTK+ API docs and can't find anything that will inhibit the window manager from applying the user's theme to my app.

While it's an assumption, I believe that it can be done, otherwise applications like Ardour, The GIMP, Lives, and Cinelerra would be impossible to run on anything except a very narrow band of system configurations.

Do any of you GTK devs have a pointer that would at least get me looking at the correct API options?

Comment: At least you can: 1) set environment variable `GTK_THEME=Adwaita`. 2) create fully custom widgets with full control of sizing and rendering (which is I think what devs of ardour and cinerella did)

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, but even setting Adwaita:dark or Adwaita:light varies from system to system.  On CentOS, my buttons end up 32 high and on Ubuntu with XOrg enabled they end up 26 high. Because the focus of my app is the content rather than the controls, I really need a way to lock things to a specific geometry.  If I have to go with fully custom controls, I may as well return to xt.